# I'm looking for cleaner way to use dot notation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a class as following, and I use NSMutableArray to store a list of MyClass objects.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject{
    NSString* _name;
}
@property(nonatomic)NSString* name;

NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];

[array addObject:[[MyClass alloc]init]];
[array addObject:[[MyClass alloc]init]];
```

I have to do the cast to get the name from array.

```
((MyClass*)array[0]).name
```

Is there a cleaner way to reference `name` from `MyClass` ?

Comment: I don't think you mean to make `_name` a `bool`.

Comment: Even better, don't explicitly declare the ivar for the `name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why @matt didn't show the syntax for lightweight generics in his answer, but here it is:

```
NSMutableArray<MyClass *>* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
```

Now the type of `array[0]` is `MyClass *` instead of just `id`, so this works:

```
array[0].name
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, my xcode is still on 6.0, I assume I update my Xcode to 7.X and should update my compiler automatically?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. You should upgrade to Xcode 7.2 unless there's a reason to stay on Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If `array` will consist *only* of MyClass objects, you can use *lightweight generics* to give the compiler a hint about what it contains, thus making the cast unnecessary.

Also, note that even without generics, you can *assign* without *casting* (because an `id` can be assigned into any object reference):

```
MyClass* c = array[0];
NSString* name = c.name;
```

Or, as @rmaddy points out, give up on dot-syntax altogether and call the getter directly; this works because any message can be sent to an `id`:

```
NSString* name = [array[0] name];
```

Alternatively, use KVC to get the `name` properties as an array:

```
NSArray* names = [array valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Objective-C *still* doesn't know what `names` consists of (unless you use lightweight generics), but now you can say e.g.

```
NSString* name = names[0];
```

Comment: See for example http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/ and many similar articles.

Comment: Or just use method syntax: `NSString *name = [array[0] name];`.

Comment: Oh yeah, nice point. I'll throw that in, but you get the credit.

Comment: +1, naturally. And should it help the original asker; lightweight generic syntax: `NSMutableArray<MyClass *> * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];`.

Comment: @Tommy go ahead and paste your code into my answer if you want.